# SetCaretPos with RichTextBox after clear text

Tags: vb.net

I have a RichTextBox with multiline enabled and v scrollbar enabled. I am having a little issue here when I press enter it shows me the entered text and it clears but the Caret position for some reason stays on the second line so I have to move it up.. how can I set the Caret at the beginning after I clear text?

Comment: Show your code.  Pressing the Enter key will create a line break.

Comment: exactly I am trying to remove that by issuing the .clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share any code, so my guess is your are clearing the text in the KeyDown event.

Simply set the e.SuppressKeyPress value to true:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) _
                                 Handles RichTextBox1.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    RichTextBox1.Clear()
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
  End If
End Sub
```